# Unable to set session variable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I have been unsuccessful in attempting to set a session variable in order to run some unit tests. I keep getting the error of "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object" when I attempt to set my session variable.

Here is the test I'm building:

```
[TestMethod]
public void MyMethod()
{
  //Arrange
  int id = 12345;
  string action = "A";
  string comment = "";
  string user = "user";
  var controller = new MyController();

  //Act
  controller.Session["altUser"] = user;
  var result = controller.Process(id, action, comment);

  //Assert
  Assert.IsNotNull(result);     
}
```

And here is my controller:

```
[Authorize]
public class MyController : Controller
{
  public ActionResult Process(int id, string action, string comment)
  {
    string userId = Session["altUser"].ToString();
    //some other stuff that evaluates ID, Action, and Comment
  }
}
```

However, when I run the application itself, there are no errors and the application functions as it should. I do understand that with Test Driven Development the tests should pave the way for the implementation. I am trying to get some practice with Unit Testing on applications that have already been done. If at all possible, since the application works, I would like to avoid making any changes to my implementation and just write a unit test to support what I already know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The controller gets the session from the `HttpContext`, which does not exist in your unit test, which is why it fails.

You can, however, mock an `HttpContext` and put a mock session in there too.

Something like this might work (uses moq as the Mocking framework)

```
    var mockControllerContext = new Mock<ControllerContext>();
    var mockSession = new Mock<HttpSessionStateBase>();
    mockSession.SetupGet(s => s["altUser"]).Returns("user");
    mockControllerContext.Setup(p => p.HttpContext.Session).Returns(mockSession.Object);

    var controller = new MyController();
    controller.ControllerContext = mockControllerContext.Object;
```

You'll obviously need to fill the mock object with the details of what you actually want to get out.

You can also derive your own classes from `HttpSessionStateBase` and `HttpContextBase` and use them instead of the real session.

Comment: When going through with using a mocking framework such as this, can I still follow the Arrange, Act, Assert pattern (it looks like the 'stage titles' when using Moq are Setup, Methods, Verify), or would is best practice to follow a different pattern? I ask this while trying to get through the QuickStart tutorial that they have.

Comment: AAA is fine - It's how most of my tests are set.

Answer (score 2):

There is no spoon, er, session — the ASP.NET runtine is neither initialized nor running when you execute the unit test. You should decompose any `Session` dependencies outside your code and make the classes and methods you need to unit test independent of ASP.NET's runtime features.

Comment: This advice was helpful for me. I ended up creating fields on the controller for storing the session variables and updating the code to refer to those fields, then initialise in the constructor. Then when unit testing I can explicitly set the fields when I instantiate the controller. :)

Answer (score 0):

When you run the unit test, you're not running the program via a web server, and therefore do not have access to any HttpContext, or ASP.NET session, whereas when you run the program via debug in VS, you are using the built in Visual Studio web server, which enables the program to use the session.

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32545/Exploring-Session-in-ASP-Net) is an article which walks you through the ASP.NET session and how it works.

Comment: That article definitely deepens my understanding about sessions. I just kind of used it in my application out of convenience and things were working well. Thanks!